# Weird Problem with Array and Boolean Modifiers

Tags: modifiers

I recognized a very weird problem when combining array and boolean modifiers at a very simple scene.

[image: weird problem with array and boolean modifiers]

Setup:

- simple cube with a simple array modifier in **X direction**
- simple cube with a simple array modifier in **Z direction**
- simple cube for boolean operation

After the array modifier I add a boolean to both simple cubes to get differenced by the boolean cube. There I recognized, that the cube with the **z direction** gets cut properly, but the one in **x direction** not. I solved this problem by simple rotating the cube 90 degrees on the y axis.

But I don't get, why this problem appears. Would be curious to know if this is a bug or if I am missing something.

Comment: Not entirely sure what the problem is. The Cube.006 is hollow? The boolean modifier indeed does weird things from time to time. I guess you already tried moving the improper booled cube a tiny bit? If that doesn't fix it and you're not in an alpha version, it's worth a bug report.

Comment: For me the problem is, that the bool leaves the booled objects "open".This means, one of the booled objects is no longer a closed volume object, but the other stays closed. This problem arrives only with the combination of this directions.

Comment: then yes, my answer remains the one above. Hollow was a bit of a bad description, but that's what I meant.